# dynamic js inclusion with requirejs

Tags: dynamic, requirejs, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm developing a single-page applications that uses `requirejs` and the `JQuery.datepicker` widget.
My site works with several languages and I would like to format the calendar according to the language settings, but I don't want to include all of the datepicker's localized files every time.

How can I manage the inclusion at runtime of the correct localized `.../jquery.ui.datepicker-_lg_.js` based on the `_lg_` variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can always `require()` the correct language file, e.g. in the application initialization code:

```
define(..., function(...) {
    var lang = ...
    require("lib/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.datepicker-" + lang, function() {
        // code here will run after the localization file has loaded
    });
    ...
});
```

If you can and do not mind putting some dynamic stuff in your `index.html` page, and the language preference is available server-side, you can even do the following:

- Separate the configuration file from your main AMD module.
- Use the `var require = ...` format for the configuration file, instead of the `require.config({...})` format.
- Assume there is a server-side variable, `lang`, that holds the language selection. In `index.html` include the scripts as (JSP-like syntax shown, adjust for your case):

  ```
  <script src="scripts/require-config.js"></script>
  <script>
      require.deps = require.deps || [];
      require.deps.push("lib/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.datepicker-<%= lang %>");
  </script>
  <script src="scripts/lib/require.js" data-main="..."></script>
  ```

This uses a little server-side code to manipulate the require configuration so as to load the localization as soon as `require` is defined. The sam principle can be used with `path` and `shim`/`deps`.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'm trying to use your code, (the first version, client-side) but I always got a "script Error" that I can't avoid. I tried to refer to relative/absolute path for the file, I included "require" as dependency of my project...but I don't understand how to load that script! Any idea?

Comment: Did you try adding the `.js` suffix?